# Read in values from file and put into a ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read in comma separated values from a text file, split the string by the commas, and then display each one of those values as a `ListTile` in a `ListView`.

I can't really figure out how to do this properly; this asynchronous code is killing me!

**tiles.txt**

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth
```

This is the code without any reading in from text file:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My App"),
        ),
        body: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final listItems = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: listItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.invert_colors),
          title: Text(listItems[index]),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index){
        return Divider();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone can figure out how to do read in from a file and display it as a `ListView` that would be great, even if it's not the way I wrote it!

Comment: yes but where are you read your text file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/csv 
Step 1: Open file in read mode

```
final input = new File('$appDocPath/tiles.txt').openRead();
```

Step 2: Use `transform` and `CsvToListConverter`

```
listItems = await input
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
    .toList();
```

Assume you have a `tile.text` in directory `/data/user/0/yourDomain.yourProjectname/app_flutter`

[image]

code snippet

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
print(appDocPath);
final input = new File('$appDocPath/tiles.txt').openRead();
listItems = await input
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
        .toList();

...
ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: listItems[0].length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.invert_colors),
                          title: Text(listItems[0][index]),
                        );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  dynamic listItems;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    print(appDocPath);
    final input = new File('$appDocPath/tiles.txt').openRead();
    listItems = await input
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
        .toList();
    print(listItems[0][0].toString());
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            listItems == null
                ? Container()
                : Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: listItems[0].length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.invert_colors),
                          title: Text(listItems[0][index]),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Divider();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```